# How to add a column to a pandas data frame that starts at a certain digit and increases by 5 every row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe in Pandas:

```
         age income     gen   wp   mp  lip
CustAtt                                   
0         45   $45k    Male   No  Yes   No
1         40   $39k  Female  Yes  Yes  Yes
2         42   $46K    Male   No   No   No
3         43   $36K    Male  Yes  Yes  Yes
4         38   $59K  Female   No  Yes  Yes
5         55   $28K  Female   No   No   No
6         35   $35K    Male   No  Yes  Yes
7         27   $26K    Male  Yes   No   No
8         43   $36K    Male   No  Yes   No
9         41   $38K  Female  Yes  Yes   No
```

and I want it to look like this data frame:

```
CustAtt     custid      age     income      gen     wp      mp      lip
0               101     45          45      male    no      yes     no
1               106     40          39      female  yes     yes     yes
2               111     42          46      male    no      no      no
3               116     43          36      male    yes     yes     yes
4               121     38          59      female  no      yes     yes
5               126     55          28      female  no      no      no
6               131     35          35      male    no      yes     yes
7               136     27          26      male    yes     no      no
8               141     43          36      male    no      yes     no
9               146     41          38      female  yes     yes     no
```

My main question is how to add the custid column so that the first value starts at 101 and increases by 5 for every row in the data frame? I know I can manually enter each number but I want to have it set so every new row it automatically increases by 5. Is this possible? Thanks for any help.

Comment: To create the column for existing data, you can use `range(start, stop, step)`: `df['custid'] = np.array(range(101, 101+len(df)*5, 5))`. But I cannot understand the "automatically increase" part. How can your dataframe be not of a fixed size upon analysis?

Comment: that's what I meant, but Is there a way to do the same thing your answer does without using numpy? only pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply multiply the number you want to increment by `df.index` and add to the base value:

```
df['custid'] = 101 + 5 * df.index
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own function to do this. It's essentially a wrapper around `range`

```
def increment_by(start, step, n):
    stop = start + step * n
    return pd.Series(range(start, stop, step))

df["cust_id"] = increment_by(start=100, step=5, n=len(df))

print(df)
   CustAtt  age  income     gen   wp   mp  lip  cust_id
0        0   45      45    male   no  yes   no      100
1        1   40      39  female  yes  yes  yes      105
2        2   42      46    male   no   no   no      110
3        3   43      36    male  yes  yes  yes      115
4        4   38      59  female   no  yes  yes      120
5        5   55      28  female   no   no   no      125
6        6   35      35    male   no  yes  yes      130
7        7   27      26    male  yes   no   no      135
8        8   43      36    male   no  yes   no      140
9        9   41      38  female  yes  yes   no      145
```